# Why can't I get Apache2 to serve sites from directories other than /var/www?

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 server running in a VirtualBox environment.  I setup a shared folder with my Windows system and this worked fine until I updated PHP to 5.5.12 from 5.3.x.  I used a new source for php as it didn't seem that apt-get was letting me upgrade past 5.3.x.  In the process it upgraded apache2 also.  One difference that I had overlooked initially was that vhost configuration files were no longer default or mysite.  The default is now 000-default.conf. And apache2.conf is only setup to load sites with configuration files that end in .conf.

The problem is not that I am getting any forbidden errors but instead apache ignores any directives telling it to use a document root elsewhere than the /var/www location.  My shared directory with VirtualBox is /media/sf_sandbox/ - that's the Ubuntu directory.  I disabled the default site 000-default.conf and enabled two others.  Now, sandbox.dev uses files in the var/www directory and not the shared directory.  It ignores the directives in the sandbox.conf file.

I read somewhere that apache by default will only serve files from the /var/www directory and that I might have to white list other directories.  It didn't say how to do that.  The apache2.conf file does have directives to load *.conf files from the sites-available directory.  Unfortunately, it just ignores the directives telling it where the document root is on my sites.  This happened after upgrading PHP from 5.3.x to 5.5.12, which also upgraded apache2.

How can I white-list other directories and tell apache to serve files from the location specified?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, this really belongs on [*Server Fault*](http://www.serverfault.com). That said, you ask this:

> How can I white-list other directories and tell apache to serve files
>   from the location specified?

There is no such thing as a “white list” for Apache. It can serve content from anywhere on your system. Even if you have a set `DocumentRoot` you can always use an `Alias`. Apache is flexible.

So what you seem to be facing is a configuration issue. Nothing more. Nothing less.  Just find the config files & adjust as needed & all should be good.

Meaning, what do you see when you run this command listing `sites-available`:

```
ls -la /etc/apache2/sites-available
```

Versus this command with `sites-enabled`:

```
ls -la /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
```

The contents of `sites-available` are the real configuration files. The items in `sites-enabled` are just symbolic links to the files in `sites-available`. So when you say this:

> The default is now 000-default.conf.

You might be mixed up. Since `000-default.conf` in `sites-enabled` is just a symbolic link to `default` in `sites-available` that Apache actually reads configurations from. For example, the contents of `sites-available` on an Ubuntu 12.04 server I am on are:

```
ls -la /etc/apache2/sites-available

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  913 Apr 15 16:15 default
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7469 Feb 14  2012 default-ssl
```

Then in `sites-enabled` it is:

```
ls -la /etc/apache2/sites-enabled

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   26 Jan 11  2013 000-default -> ../sites-available/default
```

Note how `000-default` is just a symbolic link to `../sites-available/default` which is basically `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`.

Past that you need to provide more details or look into where your configs are. And you might even try running this command to see what virtual hosts your active Apache server is currently managing:

> sudo apachectl -S

**EDIT:** Seems like the original poster does not have `000-default` in `sites-enabled`. So that can be fixed with a new symbolic link like this:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/default /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
```

Then restart Apache with a `sudo service apache2 restart` and try again. Hopefully this was the issue.  And note that the reason `default` gets renamed `000-default` when it’s in `sites-enabled` as a symbolic link is to make sure that is the very first config that is loaded.

Comment: +1 well ..explained ...:)

Comment: ls sites-available: 000-default.conf sandbox.conf contacts.conf default-ssl.conf, ls sites-enabled: contacts sandbox...  not contacts.conf, or sandbox.conf... maybe that is the problem.